# Is it possible to use the same TagHelperContext in a partial view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

I have this view (which is working fine):

```
<form asp-action="Edit" asp-orientation="Vertical" cit-ajax-modal="true">
    <modal id="language-modal" title="Hello World!">
        <modal-body>
            <validation-summary/>
            <form-group-select asp-for="CultureName" asp-items="@GlobalizationViewService.GetCultureSelectList()"/>
            <form-group-text asp-for="DisplayName"/>
            <form-group-checkbox asp-for="IsEnabled"/>
            <form-group-numeric asp-for="DefaultChance" />
        </modal-body>
        <modal-footer/>
    </modal>
</form>
```

Now I want to extract the `form-group-*` taghelpers into a partial view:

```
<validation-summary/>
<form-group-select asp-for="CultureName" asp-items="@GlobalizationViewService.GetCultureSelectList()"/>
<form-group-text asp-for="DisplayName"/>
<form-group-checkbox asp-for="IsEnabled"/>
<form-group-numeric asp-for="DefaultChance" />
```

Those TagHelpers using a `TagHelperContext` created by my `FormTagHelper` element.

So my new view is this:

```
<form asp-action="Edit" asp-orientation="Vertical" cit-ajax-modal="true">
    <modal id="language-modal" title="Hello World!">
        <modal-body>
            @Html.Partial("EditElementsPartial")
        </modal-body>
        <modal-footer/>
    </modal>
</form>
```

However, the `TagHelperContext` in the `Partial` does not include any Items created from my `FormTagHelper`.

My Basic motivation is to create a common View, which is used by an `Update` or `Create` view. `form-group-*` should get information about the `asp-orientation` from the `form` tag.

Is `Html.Partial` the wrong aproach to the problem? Any better way? Is it possible to pass the `TagHelperContext` to the Partial?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto is your editing spree [based on this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/362451/merge-tags-asp-net-core-tag-helpers-and-tag-helpers)? Seems like you are burinating `tag-helper` currently instead of merging. Also asp.net core <> mvc. Taghelpers are part of MVC, not part of core.

Comment: Lack of community support makes merging difficult, and for such a low level of questions, manual retagging is normally done. But yeah, it's part of MVC. That was likely a miss-click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to achieve what you want is to use `ViewContext.ViewData` for tag helpers communication, as discussed here: https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/3233#issuecomment-146027741